# Google does not showing my page in search results when I use js src to get content from php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-crawlers

in the name of GOD. I have a js code in a page in website 1, for showing content.

```
<script id="mdval" src="http://web1.com/api/pc.php" type="text/javascript" dval="sourceval">
```

with this method I received articles and news from database in website 2 in other server.

I dont have any problem about receiving content from website 2 and News and articles showing is very good in website 1 page. But problem is here that Google not showing website 1 page in search results. I test it in Google search after a month, but not shows the page.

Please note that I can use just client side methods with AJAX.

UPDATE:

I tested page in Fetch as Google tool. I selected fetch and render for a page that uses ajax. googlebot saw the page just like visitors with all contents and images. I click on "submit to index" for indexing page. Now after one day I searched URL in google and google listed it.

But Now problem is here that google just shows url and meta description in search results and not shows any content of the page.

please search this link in google. www.neginkoodebasir.ir/more?naapi= گیاهان مورد استفاده در تهیه کود سبز (بخش دوم)

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvjMK.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwl5s.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The google bot crawler does not parse your data that come from Ajax, it's only crawl the source of the page (CTRL + U on Chrome Windows).

Try to see with https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

You can also try to put the data from your PHP script on cache and load the cache.
And every X hours, reload the cache.

Try to see with this tool : support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for Your answering.
Please note that I can use just client side methods with AJAX and I can`t use php scripts

Comment: Sorry, I read again the google doc and it seems that Google CAN crawl your scripts:
"Times have changed. Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers. To reflect this improvement, we recently updated our technical Webmaster Guidelines to recommend against disallowing Googlebot from crawling your site's CSS or JS files."

Can you post your entire html code please ?
Maybe there is a tag "robots" or another thing.

Comment: Try to see with this tool : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en

Comment: I tested page in Fetch as Google tool.
I selected fetch and render for a page that uses ajax. googlebot saw the page just like visitors all contents and images. I click on "submit to index" for indexing page.
Now after one day I searched URL in google and google listed it.
But Now problem is here that google just shows url and description and not show any content of page.
please search this link in google.
www.neginkoodebasir.ir/more?naapi= گیاهان مورد استفاده در تهیه کود سبز (بخش دوم)

Comment: Do you want that Google show images from your site in link description, is it ?
Try to see with https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

Answer (score 0):

it seems that Google CAN crawl your scripts: "Times have changed. Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers. To reflect this improvement, we recently updated our technical Webmaster Guidelines to recommend against disallowing Googlebot from crawling your site's CSS or JS files." https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

Try to see with this tool: support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en